# Android - VoIP webcalls

Tags: android, voip, phone-call

I want to make phone calls via web using VoIP technology but I don't know how to implement this. It's there any API or something to help me implement this thing? 
I've heard of Asterisk but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could go through existing VoIP things. Maybe check out Sipdroid. Its open source too.

As far as APIs are concerned, maybe the audio capturing/playback part will give you a start.
See the Android documentation for [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) and [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html).

Comment: Oh the philosophy it's to record the audio on a call and streaming it to the web and play it again? :)

Comment: @MarcOrtiz: Pretty much, yeah. Except that there's no traditional voice call involved. Only a recording and playback on each phone.

Comment: @MarcOrtiz Yes that's right as the basic philosophy. Record from a party, put it in a data packet, send it over the web, receive, play. All this simultaneously for both parties. Also need a mechanism to initiate and end calls.

Comment: OK! Thanks :) But it may be very slowly isn't it?

Comment: not really. with proper use of threads, and balanced audio sampling bit rate etc it should be alright.